# How does merchant receive customer's info when customer use Android Pay?

Tags: android-pay

I'm interested in integrating Android Pay into my store.

> But i want to know : "when customer buy goods via Android Pay, what data i will get from customer to my server ? "

Example : https://developers.google.com/android-pay/diagrams#detailed_api_process_flow

in this guide below, at step 6 : *"the app passes the Android Pay payment credentials provided by Google in the Full Wallet to the merchant server or payment gateway."*

- I don't know what type of data i will receive, which data I can receive to my server.please give me specified example about this data ( JSON type of not ? v.v).
- How can I get list customer buy goods/service use Android Pay at my shop by API ?
- Can I send API request to Android Pay to get list customer by my goods/service?
- How can I demo 1 progress use Android Pay, i am outside US ?